# Using Bitmask to read first 2 bits of a ushort in C#

Tags: c#, bitmask, ushort

I have an array of ushorts and want to iterate over the array and check if the first two bits of that ushort are `11` if so I want to clear them. However the bit mask I am using to read the first two bits in my conditional are not working properly and the if statement does not trigger when the first two bits are `11`

```
static public void trimData(ushort[] rawData)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; i++)
   {
     if (((ushort)(rawData[i] & (1 << 15)) == 1) && ((ushort)(rawData[i] & (1 << 14)) == 1))
     {
        rawData[i] = (ushort)(rawData[i]&~(1<<15));
        rawData[i] = (ushort)(rawData[i]&~(1<<14));
     }
   }

}
```

How can I use bitmasks to do this correctly?

Comment: why not test the value of the number?

Comment: Don't compare to 1 (... == 1) but use ...!= 0

Comment: @Ecec1 I just tried that but I am still having the same issue, it does not trigger the if statement when it should

Comment: @29belgrade29 Try to debug your problem. Evaluate and display the result for '(ushort)(rawData[i] & (1 << 15))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift these bits to have them being the rightmost ones and then mask with 0b11:

```
 // drop all bits except topmost ones 16 - 14 == 2 which are now the rightmost
 int bits = (rawData[i] >> 14) & 0b11; 

 if (bits == 0b11) {
   // Both bits are set
 }
```

To clear these bits you use XOR `^` (since `1 ^ 1 == 0`):

```
 int mask = 0b11 << 14;

 // remove 14th and 15th set bits  
 rawData[i] = (ushort)(rawData[i] ^ mask);
```

Let's combine these parts:

```
 if (((rawData[i] >> 14) & 0b11) == 0b11)
   rawData[i] = (ushort)(rawData[i] ^ (0b11 << 14));
```

Finally, the method can be

```
public static void trimData(ushort[] rawData) {
  if (rawData is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rawData));

  for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; i++) 
    if (((rawData[i] >> 14) & 0b11) == 0b11)
      rawData[i] = (ushort)(rawData[i] ^ (0b11 << 14));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
static public void trimData(ushort[] rawData)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; i++)
   {
     if (49152 == (49152 & rawData[i]))
     {
        rawData = rawData.Where(x=>x != rawData[i]).ToArray();
     }
   }

}
```

49152 = (2^14) + (2^15)

Comment: This tests the two low bits. But 29belgrade29 wants to test the two high bits of his 16-bit integer.